# How to keep column MultiIndex values when merging pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two pandas DataFrames, as below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({('Q1', 'SubQ1'):[1, 2, 3], ('Q1', 'SubQ2'):[1, 2, 3], ('Q2', 'SubQ1'):[1, 2, 3]})
df1['ID'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'url':['a.com', 'blah.com', 'company.com']})
```

`df1`:

```
     Q1          Q2 ID
  SubQ1 SubQ2 SubQ1   
0     1     1     1  a
1     2     2     2  b
2     3     3     3  c
```

`df2`:

```
  item_id          url
0       a        a.com
1       b     blah.com
2       c  company.com
```

Note that `df1` has some columns with hierarchical indexing (eg. `('Q1', 'SubQ1')`) and some with just normal indexing (eg. `ID`).

I want to merge these two data frames on the `ID` and `item_id` fields. Using:

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='ID', right_on='item_id')
```

gives:

```
   (Q1, SubQ1)  (Q1, SubQ2)  (Q2, SubQ1) (ID, ) item_id          url
0            1            1            1      a       a        a.com
1            2            2            2      b       b     blah.com
2            3            3            3      c       c  company.com
```

As you can see, the merge itself works fine, but the MultiIndex has been lost and has reverted to tuples. I've tried to recreate the MultiIndex by using `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`, as in:

```
result.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(result)
```

but this causes problems with the `item_id` and `url` columns, taking just the first two characters of their names:

```
     Q1          Q2 ID  i            u
  SubQ1 SubQ2 SubQ1     t            r
0     1     1     1  a  a        a.com
1     2     2     2  b  b     blah.com
2     3     3     3  c  c  company.com
```

Converting the columns in `df2` to be one-element tuples (ie. `('item_id',)` rather than just `'item_id'`) makes no difference.

How can I merge these two DataFrames and keep the MultiIndex properly? Or alternatively, how can I take the result of the merge and get back to columns with a proper MultiIndex without mucking up the names of the `item_id` and `url` columns?

Comment: `df1.assign(u=df1.ID.map(df2.set_index('item_id')['url']))` works for you?

Comment: It works for this example, but in the real situation I have multiple columns in `df2` that I want to bring across in the join - so I'd have to do this multiple times to get each column, which I don't feel is ideal.

Answer (score 18):

If you can't beat 'em, join 'em. (Make both DataFrames have the same number of index levels before merging):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({('Q1', 'SubQ1'):[1, 2, 3], ('Q1', 'SubQ2'):[1, 2, 3], ('Q2', 'SubQ1'):[1, 2, 3]})
df1['ID'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'item_id': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'url':['a.com', 'blah.com', 'company.com']})

df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.columns, ['']])
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='ID', right_on='item_id')
print(result)
```

yields

```
     Q1          Q2 ID item_id          url
  SubQ1 SubQ2 SubQ1                        
0     1     1     1  a       a        a.com
1     2     2     2  b       b     blah.com
2     3     3     3  c       c  company.com
```

This also avoids the `UserWarning`:

> pandas/core/reshape/merge.py:551: UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (2 levels on the left, 1 on the right)

Answer (score 1):

The column for `ID` is not "non-hierarchical".  It is signified by `('ID', )`.  However, `pandas` allows you to reference just the first level of columns in a way that looks like you are referencing a single leveled column structure.  Meaning this should work `df1['ID']` as well as as `df1[('ID',)]` as well as `df1.loc[:, ('ID',)]`.  But if it happened to be that the top level `'ID'` had more columns associated with it in the second level, `df1['ID']` would return a dataframe.  I feel more comfortable with this solution, which looks a lot like @JohnGalt's answer in the comments.

```
df1.assign(u=df1[('ID', '')].map(df2.set_index('item_id').url))

     Q1          Q2 ID            u
  SubQ1 SubQ2 SubQ1                
0     1     1     1  a        a.com
1     2     2     2  b     blah.com
2     3     3     3  c  company.com
```

---

Joining on a single level column'd dataframe to a multi-level column'd dataframe is difficult.  I have to artificially add another level.

```
def rnm(d):
    d = d.copy()
    d.columns = [d.columns, [''] * len(d.columns)]
    return d

df1.join(rnm(df2.set_index('item_id')), on=('ID',))

     Q1          Q2 ID          url
  SubQ1 SubQ2 SubQ1                
0     1     1     1  a        a.com
1     2     2     2  b     blah.com
2     3     3     3  c  company.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is more flexible in the sense that you won't have to insert columns levels before concat, you can use it to concat any number of levels:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({('A', 'b'): [1, 2], ('A', 'c'): [3, 4]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Zaa': [1, 2]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({('Maaa', 'k', 'l'): [1, 2]})

df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)
cols = [col if isinstance(col, tuple) else (col, ) for col in df.columns]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)
```