# Pandas outer merge with empty data frame is causing merge warning. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am creating a data_frame with two columns, then set the index to those two columns. So it is empty but has an index. I am then joining that with another data_frame with the same index. It works but I get the following warning:

UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (2 levels on the left, 1 on the right)
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)

Am I missing something? Is there some unexpected behavior? I would like to get rid of the warning. The code is below. I am creating the one data frame in code and the other is loaded from a file.

```
def forward_fill_dates(self, start_date, end_date):
    dates = []
    current_date = start_date

    while current_date <= end_date:
        dates.append({'Date': int(f'{current_date:%Y%m%d}'), 'Bin': 0})
        current_date = bd.shift_day(current_date, 1)

    date_df = pandas.DataFrame(dates).set_index(['Date', 'Bin'])
    unstacked_df = self.other_data.unstack()
    joined_df = pandas.merge(unstacked_df, date_df, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
    self.other_df = joined_df.fillna(method='ffill').stack()
```

Comment: pandas is telling you that the two DataFrames have different index levels. It's not clear what your expected result is nor what the result of the merge was so it's impossible to know whether there is an unexpected result. To address the error message rather than suppressing it, see the `left_on` [argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge) of `pandas.merge`.

Comment: If I do the following in the debugger len(unstacked_df.index.levels) and len(date_df.index.levels) I get 2 for both. Also I switch the line of code to:
joined_df = pandas.merge(unstacked_df, date_df, how='outer', left_on=['Date', 'Bin'], right_on=['Date', 'Bin'])
I get the exact same warning message and result. My result is exactly what I would expect. It properly joins on Date-Bin. I just don't get why its warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured it out. It's not the indexes that have different levels its the data. 
I added the following line after setting the index:

```
date_df.columns = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([date_df.columns, ['']])
```

I got the answer from this post:
[How to keep column MultiIndex values when merging pandas DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801727/how-to-keep-column-multiindex-values-when-merging-pandas-dataframes?rq=1)